# How to create VSCode bindings to input bra and ket efficiently

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts, special-characters, quantum-computing, ide-customization

I'm currently using `VSCode` for `Q#` programming. This sometimes entails including simple qubit expressions in the comments for clarity. It is of course possible to just settle with using regular angle brackets (such as `|00>` or `<00|`), but it looks nicer using the appropriate Unicode characters (such as `|00⟩` or `⟨00|`). Copying and pasting these characters whenever needed is a bit cumbersome, so it would be nice to have key bindings in `VSCode` just for this purpose. Actually, I'd like to be able to configure `VSCode` for quick access to any selection of characters I might be interested at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`VSCode` customization supports a `type` command which does exactly that - types in its argument. In order to create an entry for a keybinding, open the command prompt (<kbd>Ctrl+Shift+P</kbd> or <kbd>⌘+Shift+P</kbd> on Mac) and type `Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)` and insert entries of the form:

```
{
    "key": "<key-binding>",
    "command": "type",
    "args": {
        "text": "<character>"
    }
}
```

where `<key-binding>` is the usual description of the keybinding and `<character>` is the desired character literal. So, for the bra-ket case above, my customization looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "key": "ctrl+shift+.",
        "command": "type",
        "args": {
            "text": "⟩"
        }
    },
    {
        "key": "ctrl+shift+,",
        "command": "type",
        "args": {
            "text": "⟨"
        }
    }
]
```